# How to do geography performance test with procedures

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, indexing, geospatial

I would like to test my procedure's performance with and without indexes and compare the elapsed time and cpu time. My procedure looks like:

```
create procedure p_search_vehicle
    @IdCustomer int,
    @idGroupVehicle int = null,
    @ResultCount int= null,
    @Radiant int= null 
as
begin
    if @IdCustomer is null
    begin
        print 'The argument cannot be null'
        return 
    end

    declare @start geography

    set @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer = @idCustomer)

    --- @Result null group null radiant null
    if @ResultCount is null and @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
        select top 10 
            idVehicle, idGroupVehicle, brand, model, maxRange, weight, maxSpeed, nameLocation, @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from 
            Vehicle 
        where 
            (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
        order by 
            @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
    ---@Result null  radiant null
    else if @ResultCount is null and @Radiant is null
        select top 10 
            idVehicle, idGroupVehicle, brand, model, maxRange, weight, maxSpeed, nameLocation, @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from 
            Vehicle 
        where  
            idGroupVehicle = @idGroupVehicle 
            and (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
        order by 
            @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
    ---@Result null  
    else if @Radiant is null
        select top(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
             ---@@idGroupVehicle  null @Radiant is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            ---@idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
        --- @idGroupVehicle is null 
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null 
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            --- all options
    else
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
 end
 go
```

I have tested this procedure using SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
CHECKPOINT
GO but I have to change a few things for testing to work, set all parameters permanently and throw away create procedure and declare every parameter

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE; 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
CHECKPOINT
GO
declare @IdCustomer int = 1,
 @idGroupVehicle int = null,
 @ResultCount int= null,
 @Radiant int= null 
 begin
 if @IdCustomer is null
    begin
        print 'The argument cannot be null'
        return 
    end
 declare @start geography
 SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
 ---@Result null group null radiant null
    if @ResultCount is null and @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
    begin
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
             ---@Result null  radiant null
             if @ResultCount is null and @Radiant is null
            begin
    select  top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  idGroupVehicle= 1 and (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
             ---@Result null  
             if @Radiant is null
            begin
    select TOP(5) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= 1  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
             ---@@idGroupVehicle  null @Radiant is null
             if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
            begin
    select TOP(5) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
            ---@idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
             if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
            begin
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= 1)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
        --- @idGroupVehicle is null 
             if  @idGroupVehicle is null 
            begin
    select TOP(5) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= 1)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
            --- all options
    else
    begin
    select TOP(5) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= 1  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  <= 1)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
end
```

Is it possible in some other way to test the procedures to show the execution time and row affected, without any changes to the procedure ?

Comment: `STATISTICS IO` is normally the best metric for performance, specifically `logical reads`. Much more info can be gleaned from the properties of the `execution plan` - have you reviewed each plan?

Comment: I would expect to see a lot of table scans from this proc and since `STDistance()` uses `sqrt()` operations that could get very expensive. Query planner may not be smart enough to use Spatial Indexes when it expects to see `geography1.STDistance(geography2) <= number` as the `/1000` may throw it off.

Comment: It's **search** - not "shearch" ....

Comment: Yes i review the plan but the plan of this procedure  is the same with index and without index maybe i have not enough data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to *transform* your procedure into a testing script.  Instead just *invoke* it.  And don't test with a cold procedure or page cache.  That's a highly unusual state.

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON 
GO

declare @IdCustomer int = 1,
 @idGroupVehicle int = null,
 @ResultCount int= null,
 @Radiant int= null 

exec p_search_vehicle @IdCustomer, @idGroupVehicle, @ResultCount, @Radiant
GO
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF
```